# Is there a way to block only asynchronous delivery of SIGSEGV or to find out the delivery mode?

Tags: c++, c, unix, signals, posix

In a C/C++ program, I am using `mprotect` together with an installed signal handler for SIGSEGV (using GNU libsigsegv) to implement write barriers (for generational GC). The memory protection fault signal is delivered synchronously by the kernel when the write barrier is hit.

In order to be sure that the signal handler is always being called synchronously (otherwise my code could deadlock), I would like to block asynchronous delivery of the SIGSEGV signal (e.g. through `kill (2)`). Is there a way to do this? Or is there a way for the signal handler to find out whether the signal was delivered synchronously?

Comment: ¿Could you please elaborate on the use of SIGSEGV handler in this context? Perhaps with some code example. ¿How does it help with writing GC and how are you planning to distinguish signals related to GC from those caused by other reasons?

Comment: @user7860670 The use case (garbage collection) I mentioned was just for illustration and should be mostly irrelevant for the question itself. If you want to read more about using the MMU for generational GC, the following article may help: https://medium.com/@MartinCracauer/generational-garbage-collection-write-barriers-write-protection-and-userfaultfd-2-8b0e796b8f7f.

Any synchronous invocation of my handler outside of being triggered by my write barrier is a program error.

Answer (score 0):

With the signal API you can't. But there is a workaround:

You may use realtime-extension and use `SA_SIGINFO` in the action flags to get a `siginfo_t` in your handler. In this structure you will find the pid of the emitter of the signal and can then ignore the delivery if it is not the pid of your running process?